# Markdown not being interpreted correctly on Github Pages

Tags: github, github-pages, github-flavored-markdown

I can't find the issue in my page here: https://plerpsandplerps.github.io/wyrd-tales/Player%20Character.md

The markdown is:

```
# Player Characters
Player characters are defined most importantly by the player controlling them, but they are further defined by a set of mechanics and game components. These components include: their [attributes](Attributes.md) at any given moment, their [traits](Traits.md), [abilities](Abilities.md), the cards in their [deck](Deck.md), their [items](Items), their [equipment](Equipment) their [Pacts](Pacts.md), and their [calling](Calling.md).

A player creates their initial character and then builds upon that character in the shared dreamscape called the [Night Market](Night%20Market.md).

### Three Common Elements of Player Characters
You can decide whatever you like about your character's personality, background, and appearance but all player characters must have three elements in common: 
- The [Wyrds](Wyrds) are interested in [witnessing](Witness) your player characters' actions.
    - However, the reason for their interest may vary. The [Wyrd](Wyrds) might want to see your character succeed in their [goals](Calling.md) or to see your character fail to meet their [goals](Calling.md). The [Wyrd](Wyrds) might just think your character's life would be fun to meddle with. The player decides the reason the [Wyrd](Wyrds) are interested in witnessing their character's life and it can change over time.
- The [Wyrds'](Wyrds) collective interest in the player characters'  life have granted you the opportunity to enter a shared dream, called the [Night Market](Night%20Market.md).
- The player character has been called to adventure by their [calling](Calling.md).
```

Feel like I must be missing something simple. Any help would be much appreciated. Github repo here: https://github.com/plerpsandplerps/wyrd-tales

Comment: Welcome to stack**overflow**. (I found apostrophes in unexpected places and a comma missing, but that shouldn't concern *markdown interpretation*.) How exactly does *Markdown not being interpreted correctly on Github Pages* manifest?

Comment: (Care to comment about "the other *.md*s"?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is still in the *getting words on a page* stage so there are a lot of spelling and grammatical errors.

I was able to fix this problem, by removing the `.md` in all of my links pointing to the page.